# Нужен алгоритм заполнения мест в массиве

Tags: java, android, алгоритм

Имеется диапазон чисел (тип double) от 0 до 500.
В процессе работы программы создаются маленькие интервалы, например от 4.537 до 7.654, или от 121.346 до 156.234

Необходимо в большом диапазоне (0-500) "зарезервировать" эти "маленькие" интервалы.

И когда образуется очередной "маленький" интервал, проверить, а не "занято ли место" в "большом" диапазоне. Если "занято", то "занять" хотя бы остаток.

Например: кто-то занял в большом диапазоне от 20 до 30, а новые данные хотят занять от 25 до 40, тогда должна отметится область от 20 до 40 как занятая.

Как лучше это организовать?

Comment: Только сейчас заметил слово "в массиве" в заголовке. А это принципиально, нужно именно массив использовать?

Comment: Не обязательно, просто мне кажется что с ним проще всего работать. А вообще я кажется придумал как сделать. Я сделаю массив из типов boolean? Размер массива 500*100 = 50000. Значение начала диапазонов и конца просто умножу на 100 или 1000, чтобы запятую не потерять, а потом разделю обратно, когда значение буду брать.

Comment: Дело хозяйское, но мне кажется, то, что я предложил - и проще, и гибче, и надежней. Если вам, например, понадобится занять интервал  0.00001234 .. 0.00002384736, что вы будете делать? А если завтра захочется использовать диапазон не от 0 до 500, а от -1000000 до 1000000 - сколько памяти вам надо будет докупить в машину?

Comment: Прикиньте расход памяти и время выполнения для того и другого случая. Если вам надо проверить на занятость весь диапазон от 0 до 500 с шагом 0.001, вам надо будет сделать 500 000 проверок?

Comment: Да, ваш вариант более оптимален, согласен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решений может быть много, как лучше организовать - в общем случае нельзя сказать, поскольку критерии "лучшести" могут быть разные.
Одно из возможных решений (первым пришедшее в голову): представлять занятые диапазоны в виде пар чисел '[началоДиапазона, конецДиапазона]', например `Map.Entry<Double, Double>` и хранить их в упорядоченном словаре, можно в 'TreeMap'.

При этом код для резервирования диапазона может быть примерно таким:

```
Map.Entry<Double, Double> occupy(Double rangeStart, Double rangeEnd) {
  Map.Entry<Double, Double> floor = map.floorEntry(rangeStart);
  if (floor != null && floor.getValue() >= rangeStart) {
    map.remove(floor.getKey()); 
    rangeStart = Math.min(floor.getKey(), rangeStart);
    rangeEnd = Math.max(floor.getValue(), rangeEnd);
  }
  Map.Entry<Double, Double> ceiling = map.ceilingEntry(rangeStart);
  if (ceiling != null && ceiling.getKey() <= rangeEnd) {
    map.remove(ceiling.getKey()); 
    rangeEnd = Math.max(ceiling.getValue(), rangeEnd);
  }
  map.put(rangeStart, rangeEnd);
  return map.ceilingEntry(rangeStart);
}
```

А код для проверки того, занят или нет интересу.щий вас диапазон может выглядеть как-то так:

```
/** Checks if the whole range is occupied -- no free areas */
boolean isFree(Double rangeStart, Double rangeEnd) {
  Map.Entry<Double, Double> floor = map.floorEntry(rangeStart);
  if (floor != null && floor.getValue() >= rangeStart) return false;
  Map.Entry<Double, Double> ceiling = map.ceilingEntry(rangeStart);
  if (ceiling != null && ceiling.getKey() <= rangeEnd) return false;
  return true;
}

/** Checks if the whole range is free -- no occupied areas */
boolean isOccupied(Double rangeStart, Double rangeEnd) {
  Map.Entry<Double, Double> floor = map.floorEntry(rangeStart);
  if (floor != null && floor.getValue() >= rangeEnd) return true;
  return false;
}
```

Рабочий сниппет с парой дополнительных методов и минималистским набором тестов можете посмотреть на http://ideone.com/3arRnM.
За верность и красоту кода не ручаюсь - идея не очень-то продумана и реализована наспех. Думайте, наводите красоту и тестируйте дальше сами.